# WIndows phone 8 Popup control Position

Tags: windows-phone-8, popup

What properties will make the Popup control Shows exactly over the mouse (On real device above the finger position on the screen while touching) in a windows phone application?
The xaml used is

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True"  MouseMove="mainBrowserControl_MouseMove" x:Name="mainBrowserControl"  />
        <Popup Name="ActionMenus" IsOpen="False">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" >
                <Button Name="btnA1" Click="btnAq_Click">Annotation</Button>
                <Button Name="btnHq" Click="btnHq_Click">Highlight</Button>
        </Popup>
</Grid>
```

And the code i used for showing Popup is

```
 private void mainBrowserControl_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            ActionMenus.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

But the position of the Popup is on the top of Grid . How can i make it exactly above the mousepointer (or where the user touched on the screen)

In WPF Popup i can see some more properties like Placement and if we use Placement="Mouse" the popup will shown exactly over Mouse , But this  property is missing in Windows phone

Answer (score 0):

As you have not made any Rows in your Grid, any element added to the Grid will be placed on top of all other elements.

In order to place the popup where you want it, you must find out where the user tapped. It can be found in the MouseEventArgs input to the method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Then place the ActionMenus accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you want to popup show up anywhere on the page you should:
1) Create second grid, that won't have any rows, or columns over your content (with Horizontal and Vertical aligments set to Stretch) - it will be your placing field that will take the whole page.

OR

2) Add to a popup Grid.Row and Grid.Column spans.

Next:

As emedbo said you should catch MouseDown event and get the MouseEventArgs coordinates. And then you can do:

If you selected method 1:

```
 Popup pop = new Popup();
 pop.Margin = new Thikness (X,Y,0,0) // To set margin left and top to show popups left top corner under the finger.
 Grid.Children.Add(pop);
 //Syntax maybe little incorrect, because i'm writting this from my mind
```

If you selected method 2:

```
 Popup pop = new Popup();
 pop.Margin = new Thikness (X,Y,0,0) // To set margin left and top to show popups left top corner under the finger.
 pop.*** //Here must be added Rowspan and Columnspan of the parent container
 Grid.Children.Add(pop);
 //Syntax maybe little incorrect, because i'm writting this from my mind
```

Comment: Is there any Placement="Mouse" like options are avaialable for Windows phone 8 Popup control?